# Combining different dummy variables into a single categorical variable based on conditions (mutually exclusive categories)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to `R`, and trying to create a new variable based on three dummy variables into a single categorical variable with 4 levels (0,1,2,3) which should contain mutually exclusive categories.

There are some specifications to the output I want.
If g_kom = 0 then the new variable should have the value of 0.
If g_kom = 1 then the new variable should have the value of 1.
If g_kom = 1 and v_kom = 1 then the new variable should have the value of 2. If g_kom = 1 and v_kom is 1 and a_kom is 1 then the new variable should have the value of 3.
Also the levels should be ordered from 0-3.

The challenge is that the dummy-variables I've created is not from a single categorical variable, so that the groups are not mutually exclusive across the different dummy-variables.

I've tried the following code, but all I end up with then is a dichotomous variable, and not one with 4 levels. I guess its because the groups is not mutually exclusive across the different dummy variables, but this is the part I need help with.

```
mydata1 <- mydata %>% mutate(kat_kom1 = case_when((g_kom == 0) ~ 0,
                                (g_kom == 1) ~ 1,
                                (g_kom == 1 & v_kom == 1) ~ 2,
                                (g_kom == 1 & v_kom == 1 & a_kom == 1) ~ 3))
```

As I stated previously, I am a beginner in R, so hopefully some of you with more experience may be able to provide me with an answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a key/value dataset and do a join

```
library(dplyr)
keydat <- data.frame(g_kom = 1, v_kom = c(0, 0, 1, 1), 
                       a_kom = c(0, 1, 0, 1), kat_kom1 = c(1, 4, 2, 3))

left_join(mydata, keydat) %>%
     mutate(kat_kom1 = replace(kat_kom1, g_kom == 0, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried your code, but that only gives me 3 levels, when I want 4. Also it does not seem to properly join the dataframes, as all the observations are gone. Thank you again for your reply though.

Comment: @BB1234 if you can show a small example to test, that would be great

Comment: I'm sorry! I understand that its difficult without an example, but I work with sensitive data so I cannot share it.. Rui Barradas answer did get me far though, so I think I will try to figure out that one first. If it does not work, I will try to figure out how to reproduce a small example of my data. Thank you again.

Comment: @BB1234 the join method with a key/value dataset is standard operation.  So, I am curious why it is failing for you.  It is easier to construct a small example without sharing your sensitive ddata

Comment: Sorry, my rookie mistake! I figured out what was missing. I had to assign your second line of code into a new df. Then the join method worked! I still have the same issues with NA's as I described in my comment under Rui Barradas answer though.

Comment: @BB1234. Note that this will join only when `g_kom`, `v_kom`, `a_kom` values are exactly matching the values in those correspondign keydat.  Regarding the NA values, what do you want as output when there are NA i.e. when g_kom, v_kom matches and a_kom is NA

Comment: Yeah, I guessed so - It's the same as using `case_when´. I'm not sure I understand your question, which I read as: what i want as output if g_kom and v_kom matches (both = 1), but a_kom does not match (a_kom = 0), I want it to be put in category 2 in kat_kom1. But that is already specified in the keydat, so I dont think I understand your question correctly. Could you please try to reformulate?

Comment: @BB1234 my question is that assuming your original data matches the 1 in g_kom, 0 in a_kom, but there is an NA in v_kom so it won't return the corresponding kat_kom1 because only some columns are matching and not all

Comment: I understand. I will check out the NA's to try to figure out why they are left out, and if I have some more questions I will post a comment. Thank you so much for your replies and patience!

Comment: @BB1234 I would suggest to create a simple example that shows all the cases you have and the expected output.  I don't generally read the post.  Just look at the input data and expected to get the output

Comment: Thank you for your input. I understand I will have to learn how to create a small example df. I found out why there were NAs, the missing condition were if g_kom = 1, v_kom = 0 and a_kom = 1.

Comment: @BB1234 Then, the update in my post would solve it

Comment: I tried your code but I receive the following error message: keydat <- data.frame(g_kom = 1, v_kom = c(0, 0, 1, 1), 
+                      a_kom = c(0, 1, 0, 1), kat_kom1 = c(1, 2, 3))
Error in data.frame(g_kom = 1, v_kom = c(0, 0, 1, 1), a_kom = c(0,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 4, 3

Comment: @BB1234 sorry, forgot to update the kat_kom1 Please check if that is the corresponding value `data.frame(g_kom = 1, v_kom = c(0, 0, 1, 1), 
                       a_kom = c(0, 1, 0, 1), kat_kom1 = c(1, 4, 2, 3))`

Comment: It is not correct. Now the levels are 1,4,2,3 and a category is missing (if g_kom = 0, v_kom = 0, a_kom = 0 then kat_kom1 = 0). The change you did should be placed to the value of 2 in kat_kom1, not 4.

Comment: @BB1234 You need to change the `kat_kom1 =` values based on what you needed as custom values.  I was just showing a way

Answer (score 1):

Try to also include `v_kom` and `a_kom` in the several cases, not just the next ones. Untested, since there is no data example.

```
mydata1 <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(kat_kom1 = case_when(
    (g_kom == 0) ~ 0L,
    (g_kom == 1 & v_kom == 0 & a_kom == 0) ~ 1L,
    (g_kom == 1 & v_kom == 1 & a_kom == 0) ~ 2L,
    (g_kom == 1 & v_kom == 1 & a_kom == 1) ~ 3L,
    TRUE ~ NA_integer_)
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Your code worked, except I now get some NA's. And there is no NA's in the dummy-variables, or in the variables the dummys are made of. Do you know any possible reason I would get NA's? Possibly because there are some respondents which none of the specified conditions match?

Comment: @BB1234 Yes, if none of the conditions are met then `TRUE` holds and the result is `NA_integer_`.

Comment: Thank you @Rui Barradas.